# SQL Server - comparing two variables

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I wish to compare a variable `@a` containing an entire column of a table with another variable containing a single value. Is it possible?

```
create procedure pc1(@var int)
as begin
   declare @a int

   select @a=id from tb1

   while(if exists(@var=@a))
   begin
      select * from tb1 where id=@var
   end

   return
```

end

Comment: do you want to return all records from tb1 with id matching @var? if so, a simple select should do: `select * from tb1 where id = @var`. sorry, it's not clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: No, I need to compare if @var value exists in @a where @a contains an entire field of a table.

Comment: variable `@a` does not contain "an entire column of a table". It will contain a single arbitrary value for that column from any of the rows (quite likely the highest one assuming an index on `id` but not guaranteed). What are you actually trying to do? The code you have posted doesn't make much sense. You should probably try and do it in a set based manner rather than procedurally anyway.

Comment: @Martin :I want to get the corresponding record from a table, if the value am passing to the procedure exists in the table. By the way, set based manner means? Please explain as I am a newbie..

Comment: @user1080139 - set based means that instead of processing row by (agonizing) row you write a query that does what you want to the whole set of rows. I'm still not clear what you are trying to do in your `WHILE` loop so can't be much more specific than that at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way but you can do this thing in following way.

```
declare @a int
Set @a = 1


if exists(
   select @a as ID
   Intersect
   Select ID 
   from tbl
)
Print('Hello')
```